# Bus Error 10 from Filter # Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

So I am using Keras with Tensorflow as the backend for an image classification problem. This is done in Python3, using Anaconda for my VM, on Mac.

Anyway the issue is this:

I am using a simple 3D convolutional neural net here:

```
 convo_net = Sequential()
 convo_net.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3,3,3), input_shape=(1, 21, 256, 176), data_format='channels_first'))
 convo_net.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
 convo_net.add(Dropout(.5))
 convo_net.add(Flatten())
 convo_net.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 convo_net.add(Dropout(.5))
 convo_net.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
 convo_net.add(Dropout(.5))
 convo_net.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
 convo_net.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
 convo_net.fit(training_set, training_labels, epochs=1, batch_size=3)
 scores = convo_net.evaluate(testing_set, testing_labels)
 sc = scores[1]
 print(sc*100)
```

And so the thing is, that network I listed above runs just fine.

HOWEVER,

If I change the # of filters to use for convolution (as defined by the first parameter in the declaration of Conv3D) to anything less than 32, I get this error (also I haven't tried more than 32 filters but that's beside the issue since I would like fewer to improve runtime):

```
Bus error: 10
```

And that's it, nothing else. I am absolutely certain nothing else (in the code at least) is causing the error as I have checked thoroughly. It is *definitely* lowering the number of filters from 32. All of my packages and dependencies are up to date to. I am at a complete loss as to why this error is happening and can't find anyone else having any issue similar!